# Live Stream web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming

What's the recommended solution to build a ruby on rails app that streams audio/video using microphone& camera, and get watched by all subscribers users ?

what's the recommended services to use ? what's the needed tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the link below: OpenTok developed by a University.

http://tokbox.com/opentok

Comment: I want to know open source tools which can i use

Comment: That is open source. It's a video chat application allowing multiple users to join a video call